# Insert textbox in datatable but having difficulty to save all the records

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi i am adding a textbox in a datatable where the user will input data in each row. I need help on how to save the data...because right now it's saving only the last row. Please see code below, can someone help on this? I think there should be some sort of array but i dont know if it is possible to store value in array using el expression. I implemented a nested datatable since i want the data to be side by side. If you have a better idea other than using datatable , I would be glad if you could share it and give proper instruction on how to proceed. ( but it should be side by side) 
Thanks in advance

```
<p:dataTable id="dta" value="#{MyCarComponent.model}" var="cur" rows="15" >

<p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
       <h:outputText value="Model:" />
     </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{current.cptModel}" />
</p:column>

<p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Type:" />
    </f:facet>
    <p:dataTable id="dta1" value="#{cur.type}" var="curType" rows="15" >
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{curType.cptType}" />
        </p:column>


        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Origin:" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:form>
                <p:dataTable id="dta3" value="#{curType.origins}" var="curOrigin"           rows="15" >
                    <p:column>
                       <h:outputText value="#{curOrigin.origin}" />
                     </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                           <h:inputText 
                         value="#{MyCarComponent.origindetails.country}"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </h:form>
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
</p:column>

<f:facet name="footer">

       <p:commandButton image="save" ajax="false" value="Save" action=" #.       {Mycar.saveMyCar(curOrigin.origin,MyCarComponent.origindetails)}" />
</f:facet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently binding the input field of **all** rows to one and same bean property. So when JSF processes the form submit in the same sequence as the component tree, the value of each input field will be set in this one and same property. Of course the property will end up being the one of the last row.

You just need to bind the value of the input field to the currently iterated row, the `#{curOrigin}`. E.g.

```
<h:inputText value="#{curOrigin.country}" />
```

Just create the property of there if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I can't do this. the field country is not accessible from the variable curOrigin. "curOrigin.origin and MyCarComponent.origindetails.country", these 2 fields come from 2 different tables, but when i click on save , it will be stored in another table( both field together)

Comment: Then your model is broken. You'd need to fix your model as such that the view can use it. That the model for your view can't be the same model for the DB is a different problem which can be solved with bean mapping (e.g. DTOs) or by *also* fixing the DB model.

Comment: if i put the inputext(MyCarComponent.origindetails.country) alone in another datatable, will it work?

Comment: Of course not. You would then still end up with multiple input fields being bound to a single property. This just doesn't make any sense. Each input field must have its own unique property so that the submitted values won't override each other until the last one. You also can't assign one `String` variable multiple different values on demand. You'd need e.g. `String[]`, `List<String>` or `Map<K, String>`.